# kendo treeview multiple node drag and drop

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have One Kendo Tree-view with check-box. I am able to drag and drop single item(node).Now I want to drag and drop multiple Item(node). only those nodes will be drag and drop which check-box are checked. Please help me out how can be i implement this functionality.........

for single drag and drop i am following this example----

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/treeview/dragdrop.html[image]

USER CAN ABLE TO DRAG AND DROP AS MANY NODES HE SELECTED IN CHECKBOX.

According to MY RND

`Below code section from kendo.web.js`

```
     dragstart: function (e) {
        /*  Here Kendo UI StartDRAGGING*/

        console.log(e);
        var that = this,
            treeview = that.treeview,
            sourceNode = that.sourceNode = e.currentTarget.closest(NODE);

         // here how can i find how many node are selected 

        if (treeview.trigger(DRAGSTART, { sourceNode: sourceNode[0] })) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        that.dropHint = $("<div class='k-drop-hint' />")
            .css(VISIBILITY, "hidden")
            .appendTo(treeview.element);
    }
```

Comment: What happens with the nodes not checked? It is very intuitive drag a node and all its sub-nodes (i.e. a branch) to a different node in the same or different tree but it is not intuitive to me what mean drag some nodes since the structure is not preserved. Could you elaborate a little more your problem?

Comment: I don't want to preserve my structure. Because at the end i need only json(updated) what did user changes by drag and drop.

Comment: Some sort of, still some doubts on what happens if you have checkboxes at different levels. Ex: you have checked `BEER` and under `BEER` you have `CORONA BEER` and `FOSTER CAN BEER`. When you drag and drop it under `BREEZERS`, what happens with the `BEER` children that are not checked?

Comment: after discussion with my manager. he was saying OK. then we will give multiple drag and drop with same level. for example--1...
if user checked on
      CORONA BEER    and
      STELLA BEER   then he can able to drag and drop inside beer children which are different from checked children. as like
      FOSTER CAN BEER. he can't be able to drag and drop with different level.