# Kendo tree view populate using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am new in kendo ui. and i want to populate treeview.
My Json format is like that:-----

```
         {
        "GetMenu": [
          {
            "OutletCode": "BOL",
            "MenuGroup": [
              {
                "ParentId": 1,
                "ItemName": "BEER",
                "Items": [
                  {
                    "ItemId": 239,
                    "ParentId": 1,
                    "ItemName": "HEINEKEN PINT BEER",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  },
                  {
                    "ItemId": 241,
                    "ParentId": 1,
                    "ItemName": "HEINEKEN BOTLLE",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "ParentId": 2,
                "ItemName": "BREEZERS",
                "Items": [
                  {
                    "ItemId": 110,
                    "ParentId": 2,
                    "ItemName": "BACARDI BREEZER",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

In treeView I want Output some thing like that:---

[image]

I want final treeview like that only.

Note:--> for saving space i escape some value from json as like:

```
 R BOTLLE
 AMSTEL LIGHT BOTTLE
 FOSTER BOTLLE
 KINGFISHER BEER BOTTLE
 HEINEKEN CAN BEER
```

I want answer in javascript or jquery only.

may be I can override in original kendoui.

if this type of question asked before then let me know the link....
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Your Json Data
var jsondata = {
        "GetMenu": [
          {       
            "OutletCode": "BOL",
            "MenuGroup": [

              {
                "ParentId": 1,
                "ItemName": "BEER",
                "Items": [
                  {
                    "ItemId": 239,
                    "ParentId": 1,
                    "ItemName": "HEINEKEN PINT BEER",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  },
                  {
                    "ItemId": 241,
                    "ParentId": 1,
                    "ItemName": "HEINEKEN BOTLLE",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "ParentId": 2,
                "ItemName": "BREEZERS",
                "Items": [
                  {
                    "ItemId": 110,
                    "ParentId": 2,
                    "ItemName": "BACARDI BREEZER",
                    "Price": "35.000"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
         }]
      };


var testArray = new Array();
var testObject = new Object(); 
testObject.ItemName = jsondata.GetMenu[0].OutletCode;
testObject.Items =  jsondata.GetMenu[0].MenuGroup;
testArray.push(testObject);



$( document ).ready(function() {  

var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                    data: testArray,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                                children: "Items"
                        }
                    }
                });

                $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: inlineDefault ,
            dataTextField: "ItemName",

                });
}); 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
  <div id="treeview-left"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ivyansh9897/QgV53/1/
Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thanks Jayesh.
but in this Structure OutletCode node is not their. you can see First node is BOL which is OutletCode .

Comment: Can you tell me from which line number i should debug the kendo ui

Comment: I have updated my above code snippet. Please check it and let me know if any concern.

Comment: thanks jayesh ji that is working before that i didnot get idea array of object will also work here thanks man. i will upvote your answer.
RAM RAM boss

Comment: Your Json result is not valid datasource for KendoTreeView, That's why i have modiefied your json result. Let me know if any part of above code snippet is not understandable.

Comment: yes   but what ever web-service return to me as it as i show to you

Comment: one more Request Jayesh G Can Look my  another question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830733/kendo-treeview-multiple-node-drag-and-drop

Comment: I will try to resolved it. Once i will get the solution i will update it. In-addition, @OnaBai has already checked your question and he is the best problem solver for Kendo-UI in the world. So will definitely get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="treeview"></div>
<script>
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: [
                  { text: "BOL",expanded:true, items: [
                          { text: "Beer",expanded:true,items:[{
                              text:"HEINEKEN CAN BEER"},
                              {text:" KINGFISHER BEER BOTTLE"}] 
                          },
                    { text: "Breezers",expanded:true,items:[{
                              text:"HEINEKEN CAN Breezer"},
                              {text:" KINGFISHER Breezer BOTTLE"}] 
                          },
                      ]
                    },]
            });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: dataSource 
            });


        </script>
```

Comment: I need to pass my json as it is.

Comment: Can you tell me from which line number i should debug the kendo ui.

Comment: while submitting try JSON.stringify($('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView').dataSource)

Comment: you will get the json data in the string format and you can submit it to the controller